# Using dictionary replacement with df.at[] output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have multiple dictionaries in which I am trying to replace the values of a column in a dataframe based on the value of another column. I have a dataframe with `country` and `state` columns. The `country` column is a string and the `state` column is numeric. My dictionaries look like this:

```
us_state = {1: 'Alabama', 2: 'Alaska', 3: 'Illinois', 4: 'Ohio'}
can_state = {1: 'Edmonton, 2: 'Sasketchwan', 3: 'Manitoba'}
```

My original thought was to use a for loop and a conditional on the `country` column. If country is equal to some value, use this list:

```
def convert_state(df):
    for i, j in df.iterrows():
        if j['country'] == 'United States':
            df.at[i, 'state_edit'] = df.at[i, 'state'].replace(us_state)
        if j['country] == 'Canada':
            df.at[i, 'state_edit'] = df.at[i, 'state'].replace(can_state)
```

The error I get is `AttributeError: 'numpy.int8' object has no attribute 'replace'`. This has to do with the output of `df.at[]` which I am unsure of how to handle. I tried converting it to a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame()`, but got another error. How would I make this approach work - using a conditional and applying the right dictionary?

Here is an example of the dataframe

```
  import pandas as pd
    data = {'country':['United States', 'United States', 'Canada', 'United States'], 'state':[4, 2, 2, 1]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

state_edit gets created as a third column in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` to conditionally pick up mapped states based on the country:

```
import numpy as np

df['state_edit'] = np.where(
  df.country.eq('United States'), 
  df.state.map(us_state), 
  df.state.map(can_state)
)

df    
         country  state   state_edit
0  United States      4         Ohio
1  United States      2       Alaska
2         Canada      2  Sasketchwan
3  United States      1      Alabama
```

Or use `numpy.select` if you have multiple conditions:

```
df['state_edit'] = np.select(
   [df.country == 'United States', df.country == 'Canada'], 
   [df.state.map(us_state), df.state.map(can_state)]
)

df
         country  state   state_edit
0  United States      4         Ohio
1  United States      2       Alaska
2         Canada      2  Sasketchwan
3  United States      1      Alabama
```

Comment: I like how simple this is - how would it scale if there were three or more dictionaries?

Comment: This is highly scalable compared to your solution which is very inefficient since you are iterating the dataframe with `iterrows` instead of vectorizing it.

Comment: @GK89 You can use `numpy.select` if you have more countries to map to. Updated the answer.